# Array with Map() changes shape and becomes nested when code is compiled

Tags: javascript, typescript

In my application I'm using `Map()` to remove duplicate items from an array:

```
const uniqueTree = [
  ...new Map(
    [newItem, ...oldData]
  ).values(),
]
```

In development this returns a flat array that looks like this:

```
[
  object1,
  object2,
  object3
  // etc
]
```

However, after compiling my code, the array looks like this:

```
[
  MapIterator: [
    object1,
    object2,
    object3
    // etc
  ]
]
```

How it appears in the console 
[image]

I compile my package with Rollup by using a utility called [`tsdx`](https://tsdx.io/)

I'm not entirely sure what's happening, is there any way to avoid this?

Edit:

Here's my tsconfig:

```
{ 
   "extends": "@tsconfig/create-react-app/tsconfig.json", 
   "include": ["src", "types"] 
 }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what do you mean by "in development" and "after compiling"?

Comment: What is your tsconfig?

Comment: This is a fairly odd use of `Map`. Do you mean to use `Set`?

Comment: @motto Yes I did, however that has the same exact problem!

Comment: @vr. Edited with my tsconfig

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I compile my package with `tsdx`, which uses rollup. Does that help?

Comment: I think the culprit is [this line](https://github.com/tsconfig/bases/blob/d699759e29cfd5f6ab0fab9f3365c7767fca9787/bases/create-react-app.json#L9). Have you tried overriding this in your tsconfig to a more recent version? ES6 or ESNext perhaps?

Comment: I will play around with it, I didn't even consider those configs could be out of date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the code is being transpiled into an es6 "MapIterator" instead of an array of objects.

Try:

```
const uniqueTree = [
  ...Array.from(
    new Map(
      [newItem, ...oldData]
    ).values()
  )
];
```

Normally though, seeing as you're only really interested in the values of the map, I'd be inclined to use `new Set` to remove duplicates.

```
const uniqueTree = Array.from(new Set([newItem, ...oldData]));
```